# Bad Data when use Decrypt and Encrypt in c# mvc

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I am using `Decrypt` and `Encrypt` with C# and am getting this error

> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 64:                 CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
>   des.CreateDecryptor(DecryptKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write); Line 65:
>   cs.Write(inputByte, 0, inputByte.Length); Line 66:
>   **cs.FlushFinalBlock(); Line 67:**                 System.Text.Encoding
>   encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; Line 68:                 return
>   encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());

How do I solve this problem; this is my code

```
  public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            string key = "amir100amir*&%$#";
            byte[] EncryptKey = { };
            byte[] IV = { 55, 34, 87, 64, 87, 195, 54, 21 };
            EncryptKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 8));
            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] inputByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, des.CreateEncryptor(EncryptKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cStream.Write(inputByte, 0, inputByte.Length);
            cStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray()).Replace("/", "_").Replace("+", "-");


        }


        public static string encodeSTROnUrl(string thisEncode)
        {
               if (null == thisEncode)
                    return string.Empty;

               return (Encrypt(thisEncode));

        }

        public static string decodeSTROnUrl(string thisDecode)
        {
            //thisDecode = thisDecode.Replace(" ", "+");
             // return Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(thisDecode));
            return Decrypt((thisDecode));
        }


        public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
        {
           // try
            {

                encryptedText = encryptedText.Replace("_", "/");
                encryptedText = encryptedText.Replace("-", "+");
                string key = "amir100amir*&%$#";
                byte[] DecryptKey = { };
                byte[] IV = { 55, 34, 87, 64, 87, 195, 54, 21 };
                byte[] inputByte = new byte[encryptedText.Length];
                DecryptKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 8));
                DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                inputByte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(DecryptKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(inputByte, 0, inputByte.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());



            }
            //catch
            //{

            //}
            //finally { }
            //return "Error";
        }
```

Comment: Which line of your code is generating the error? How are you calling these functions?

Comment: `decodeSTROnUrl(encodeSTROnUrl("Very secret"));` seems to work. Can you provide more details ?

Comment: The code works for me. But I'm using basic ascii strings; Encrypting 'meep_meep' and decrypting it results in the expected behaviour. Can we see what the string is that OP is encrypting? Perhaps it contains non-standard characters.

Comment: Seems to work for Chinese as well `極秘`

Comment: cs.FlushFinalBlock();  is error

Comment: IV should be cryptographic random generated and transmitted along with the encrypted text (eg. prepended). Right now you use a static IV, thus defeating its purpose.